# Can not install R packages on CentOS

Tags: r, package, centos6

Here is my system info.

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 18:37:12 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Here is my R info

```
> R.version
               _
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          2.3
year           2015
month          12
day            10
svn rev        69752
language       R
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree
```

I got the following error message while trying to install R package.
It happens not only for the `ggvis` package, but most other packages.

command

```
install.packages("ggvis", dependencies=TRUE, repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

error

```
* installing *source* package ‘ggvis’ ...
** package ‘ggvis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  object 'vI' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggvis’
* removing ‘/vagrant/packrat/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/3.2.3/ggvis’
* restoring previous ‘/vagrant/packrat/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/3.2.3/ggvis’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpUju5PK/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("ggvis", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("http://rstudio.org/_packages",  :
  installation of package ‘ggvis’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Are you trying to install from a local repository, or from a CRAN mirror?

Comment: from a CRAN mirror, see update above.

Comment: Hmm, try using `repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/"`.

Comment: Thanks, but I did try that first, and I got the following error.

`> install.packages("tidyr", dependencies=TRUE, repos=c("https://cran.rstudio.com"))
Installing package into ‘/root/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  unsupported URL scheme
Warning message:
package ‘tidyr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)`

Comment: That's strange, `install.packages("tidyr", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/")` works for me on a CentOS 7 machine using R 3.2.3.